# An issue with posting a reply in the Django website

Tags: python, django

I am following the tutorial on [Protecting Views][1] and I have trouble understanding the tutorial.  When I click the the Reply Button, it does not take me to the link to reply to the topic, and displayed a # in the URL instead. I had to type in the URL to get to that point.  And when I posted something, it didn't redirect, and the new topic that I replied to wasn't there. I don't know why this is happening.

Here's my forms.py file

```
from django import forms

from .models import Topic, Post

class NewTopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    message = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(),
        max_length=4000,
        help_text='The max length of this field is 4000.'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['subject', 'message']

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['message', ]
```

and here's my urls.py file

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
    
    from accounts import views as accounts_views
    from boards import views
    
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
        url(r'^signup/$', accounts_views.signup, name='signup'),
        url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
        url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    
        url(r'^reset/$',
            auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
                template_name='password_reset.html',
                email_template_name='password_reset_email.html',
                subject_template_name='password_reset_subject.txt'
            ),
            name='password_reset'),
        url(r'^reset/done/$',
            auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_done.html'),
            name='password_reset_done'),
        url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
            auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_confirm.html'),
            name='password_reset_confirm'),
        url(r'^reset/complete/$',
            auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_complete.html'),
            name='password_reset_complete'),
    
        url(r'^settings/password/$', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='password_change.html'),
            name='password_change'),
        url(r'^settings/password/done/$', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='password_change_done.html'),
            name='password_change_done'),
    
        url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.board_topics, name='board_topics'),
        url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/new/$', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
        url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/topics/(?P<topic_pk>\d+)/$', views.topic_posts, name='topic_posts'),
        url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/topics/(?P<topic_pk>\d+)/reply/$', views.reply_topic, name='reply_topic'),
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
And here is my views.py file
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render

from .forms import NewTopicForm, PostForm
from .models import Board, Post, Topic


def home(request):
    boards = Board.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'boards': boards})


def board_topics(request, pk):
    board = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'topics.html', {'board': board})


@login_required
def new_topic(request, pk):
    board = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewTopicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            topic = form.save(commit=False)
            topic.board = board
            topic.starter = request.user
            topic.save()
            Post.objects.create(
                message=form.cleaned_data.get('message'),
                topic=topic,
                created_by=request.user
            )
            return redirect('topic_posts', pk=pk, topic_pk=topic.pk)
    else:
        form = NewTopicForm()
    return render(request, 'new_topic.html', {'board': board, 'form': form})


def topic_posts(request, pk, topic_pk):
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, board__pk=pk, pk=topic_pk)
    return render(request, 'topic_posts.html', {'topic': topic})


@login_required
def reply_topic(request, pk, topic_pk):
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, board__pk=pk, pk=topic_pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.topic = topic
            post.created_by = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('topic_posts', pk=pk, topic_pk=topic_pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'reply_topic.html', {'topic': topic, 'form': form})
```

and here's my templates/reply_topic file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title %}Post a reply{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumb %}
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Boards</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'board_topics' topic.board.pk %}">{{ topic.board.name }}</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'topic_posts' topic.board.pk topic.pk %}">{{ topic.subject }}</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Post a reply</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

  <form method="post" class="mb-4" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% include 'includes/form.html' %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Post a reply</button>
  </form>

  {% for post in topic.posts.all %}
    <div class="card mb-2">
      <div class="card-body p-3">
        <div class="row mb-3">
          <div class="col-6">
            <strong class="text-muted">{{ post.created_by.username }}</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 text-right">
            <small class="text-muted">{{ post.created_at }}</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        {{ post.message }}
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

I followed the tutorial exactly, but the reply worked when I typed in the URL, not when I clicked on the reply button.  Is there an explanation for this, or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know if I am following the tutorial correctly. I get frustrated when things don't go my way.  Like I want my programs to work.

Comment: It turns out that errors aren't a bad thing.  They are a necessary evil because they can help you improve.  It's best not to think of errors as stepping stones, but as guides to help you in the long run.